# How to get screen resolution of a client system by using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am developing a website,my webpage consist of many products. on clicking over a product i must show the details of that product in popup window.For setting the popup window to full window, i want to get client system resolution, so that it may easy to show the popup window in full screen according to resolution.
Can any one please help me to sort a way to solve this problem by using JavaScript or any other method.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't always have a popup cover the whole screen. Consider Windows' task bar and Mac OS X's menu bar. Different Linux distributions might even have crazier reserved areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the client's window dimensions with Javascript:

```
     var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
     var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Comment: This gets you the size of the *window*. The OP wants the size of the *screen*.

Comment: @John Flatness, Oh! I see. You're right. He might just be referring to the *inside-browser-window-screen*.

Comment: this returns the dimensions of the viewport, not of the screen.

Comment: how to get the values of "windowWidth" and "windowHeight" in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript variables `screen.width` and `screen.height` work well enough in most browsers.

You will however have to subtract a few pixels off the height for the title bar and what not.